# Regex match everything between dot '.' and close brace '('

Tags: javascript, regex, sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting

I have `myObject.myFunction()` and I want to match `myFunction` in a regular expression. If I want to match everything between two strings, the expression `abc(.*)def` works; so `var str = 'abc test def';str.match(/.(.*)def/)` would return `["abc test def", " test "]` as expected. But the expression `.(.*)(` does not work. I want to add a Javascript Syntax to my sublime text 2. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But the expression .(.*)( does not work.

Because `.` is a special character in regular expressions. To match a literal `.`, escape it: `\.`

`(` is also special, so you need to escape it as well:

```js
var str = "/* Some function call */ myObject.myFunction() /* stuff */";
var match = str.match(/\.(.*)\(/);
document.body.innerHTML = match[1];
```

Since `.*` is a greedy subpattern, it matches up to the last `(` on the line. You may use a negated character class `[^(]*` to match up to the first `(`:

```js
var str = "/* Some function call */ myObject.myFunction() { var str = \"String ()\";} /* stuff */";
document.body.innerHTML += str.match(/\.([^(]*)/)[1] + "<br/>";
document.body.innerHTML += str.match(/\.(.*)\(/)[1];
```

Comment: OP Should keep in mind that using regex to parse a programming language like this is a fool's errand. For example, `/\.(.*)\(/` will match any "function calls" in written in comments or the following `.myFunction("test with a parenthesis("`

Comment: Yes, not suitable for anything that needs to be more than a 90% solution. Usually "good enough" for some simple syntax highlighting, but even then regex is only part of the solution.

Comment: absolutely. I just wanted to make a note here just in case OP was trying to do anything more than syntax highlighting. :) Good answer